# Flutter lazy loading with listview mysql

Tags: mysql, flutter

Good day i want to put my listview i into a lazy loading

```
  class Done extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _DoneState createState() => _DoneState();
    }
    
    class _DoneState extends State<Done> {
      final money = NumberFormat("#,##0", "en_US");
      var loading = false;
      final list = new List<Vessel_tranasction>();
      final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refresh =
          GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
```

this is my http request to get data in my sql database.

```
   Future<void> getData() async {
        list.clear();
        setState(() {
          loading = true;
        });
        Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        SharedPreferences preferences = await _prefs;
        String id = preferences.getString("id");
        final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.done + "?client_signature=$id");
        debugPrint(response.body);
        if (response.contentLength == 2) {
        } else {
```

This is my Json map

```
final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      data.forEach((api) {
        final ab = new Vessel_tranasction(
            api['id'],
            api['status'],
            api['typeofport'],
            api['vesselid'],
            api['transaction_id'],
            api['anchor_eta'],
            api['anchor_ata'],
            api['anchor_etd'],
            api['anchor_atd'],
            api['berth_eta'],
            api['berth_ata'],
            api['berth_etd'],
            api['berth_atd']
           );

        list.add(ab);
      });
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

this is my initstate to initialize my get data?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
```

This is my listview i want to put a lazy loading on it given here my data the date and time the vessel name shipcall numbers and vogayage number and payment

```
   @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: getData,
          key: _refresh,
          child: loading
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: list.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    final x = list[i];
                    debugPrint(x.toString());
                    return ExpansionTile(
                      title: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                              'Transaction ID:\t' +
                                  x.transaction_id +
                                  '\nVesselname:\t' +
                                  x.vesselname +
                                  '\nVoyage #:\t' +
                                  x.voyageno,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                            title: Text('Ship Call #:\t' + x.scn,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))),
                        ListTile(
                          title: x.anchor_eta == null
                              ? Text(
                                  'Anchorage Estimated Time of Arrival:\n 00-00-0000 00:00 ',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))
                              : Text(
                                  'Anchorage Estimated Time of Arrival:\n' +
                                      formatDate(x.anchor_eta),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: x.anchor_ata == null
                              ? Text(
                                  'Anchorage Actual Time of Arrival :\n 00-00-0000 00:00',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))
                              : Text(
                                  'Anchorage Estimated Time of Arrival:\n' +
                                      formatDate(x.anchor_ata),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: x.anchor_etd == null
                              ? Text(
                                  'Anchorage Estimated Time of Departure :\n 00-00-0000 00:00',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))
                              : Text(
                                  'Anchorage Estimated Time of Arrival:\n' +
                                      formatDate(x.anchor_etd),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: x.anchor_atd == null
                              ? Text(
                                  'Anchorage Actual Time of Departure :\n 00-00-0000 00:00',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))
                              : Text(
                                  'Anchorage Estimated Time of Arrival:\n' +
                                      formatDate(x.anchor_atd),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: x.berth_eta == null
                              ? Text(
                                  'Berth Estimated Time of Arrival :\n 00-00-0000 00:00',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))
                              : Text(
                                  'Berth Estimated Time of Arrival:\n' +
                                      formatDate(x.berth_eta),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: x.berth_ata == null
                              ? Text(
                                  'Berth Actual Time of Arrival :\n 00-00-0000 00:00',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))
                              : Text(
                                  'Berth Actual Time of Arrival:\n' +
                                      formatDate(x.berth_ata),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: x.berth_etd == null
                              ? Text(
                                  'Berth Estimated Time of Departure :\n 00-00-0000 00:00',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))
                              : Text(
                                  'Berth Estimated Time of Departure:\n' +
                                      formatDate(x.berth_etd),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: x.berth_atd == null
                              ? Text(
                                  'Berth Actual Time of Departure :\n 00-00-0000 00:00',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))
                              : Text(
                                  'Berth Actual Time of Departure:\n' +
                                      formatDate(x.berth_atd),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text('Status:\t' + x.status.toUpperCase(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: x.status == 'pending'
                                      ? Colors.red
                                      : Colors.green)),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
        ));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, try to rephrase it. Do you want to implement MySql instead of Shared Preferences?

Comment: sorry sir by the way i want to put my listview in a lazy loading